# Sequence of CGAffineTransform on a Single UIView

Tags: objective-c, uikit, core-graphics, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to combine `CGAffineTransform` animations like rotate, scale and what not.

My problem with scaling and rotating is that if I do them in sequence, when I scale down/up my view and then rotate afterwards; while rotating, the view goes back to its original scale, it doesn't stay in the new scale I specified.

How can I scale, rotate, fly, scale again and rotate again?

I learned that I can use `CGAffineTransformConcat()`to combine 2 `CGAffineTransform` like scale and rotate.

But is it possible to use concat to achieve what I want where I have combinations of CGAffineTransform that execute at the same time and then continue with the sequence? or is there a way to do that even without using `CGAffineTransformConcat`? I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: CGAffineTransformConcat() combines transforms in the sense that they are executed at the same time, not in sequence. If you want to do it in sequence, you had to start the next animation in the completion handler of the 1st one.

Comment: Hi Reinhard. I see. But if let's say I rescale the view and then after finishing I rotate it, during rotation, the view goes back to its original scale. 

How can I achieve scaling the view and then rotating using the new scale I set?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I updated my questions to clearly say what I want. I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are doing is something like this...

```
//scale
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);

//rotate
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

However, this applies the transform to the identity transform so `scale` will be set back to `1.0` when you rotate.

So you need to do something like...

```
//scale
view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 2.0, 2.0);

//rotate
view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, M_PI);
```

This takes the current transform and applies the new transform to it.

Comment: Hi @Fogmeister thank you so much for this. I have one last question, Can I combine more than 2 CGAffineTransform animations? Like I want my view to rotate,scale,fly up at the same time. Can I add a CGAffineTransformConcat inside another CGAffineTransformConcat? I tried and it doesn't seem to work or maybe I was doing it wrong or something.

Comment: @user1681701 Yeah, just build up the transform one at a time. You can add as many as you want.

Comment: how about moving? I tried doing CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation to move but it just disappeared. Do you know how may I make it move at the same time?

Comment: @user1681701 You are using `MakeTranslation` you need to use `Translate` on it's own. Also, be careful of the order in which you do them. If you do a scale of 2x, then a rotation of 90 degrees clockwise, then a translation of 10 points right. The translation will actually be `20` points `down` because the previous transforms change the vector space that is being used.